# White holes and trans-Planckian NEC instabilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, white-holes

According to some recent work by [Carlo Rovelli](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04147), Planckian white holes are effectively immune to perturbations, due to the fact that any perturbations that could destabilize them would have to be smaller than the Planck length, and thus forbidden in quantum gravity.

White holes violate the Null Energy Condition, and thus would seem to fall under the work of [Stephen D. Hsu](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0502203), who demonstrated for a broad class of models that systems which violated the NEC would be unstable to small perturbations.

Given the above information, would Planckian white holes be protected from NEC instabilities, in that those instabilities would be required to be below the Planck length, and thus be forbidden?